# Get and set to private variables in java

Tags: java, get, field, private

Good day,

I am new to JAVA'm learning this language and what I have learned it seems a fantastic language. My question is in relation to the following:

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
public class Person{
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private int age;
   private String entireName;

   public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getEntireName() {
    return entireName;
}

public void setEntireName(String entireName) {
    this.entireName = entireName;
}

   public static void Main(String args[]){
          Person person = new Person();
          person.setFirstName("Jhon");
          person.setLastName("Adams");
          person.setAge(20);
          //Atention this line
          person.setEntireName(person.getFirstName()+person.getLastName());
       }
}
```

The language allows me to do this: `person.setEntireName(person.getFirstName()+person.getLastName());` 
and it works fine however I would like to know how is best to do this, how it behaves at the object level and how high or low the performance.

Thank you ..

Comment: Yes it would allow you to do this, `person.setEntireName(person.getFirstName()+person.getLastName());`, and you would *never* want to do this -- try and re-set an object's fields with its own fields. Crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is valid. There is no performance difference, becasue JIT compiler optimize this code if needed (simply replace method with fields access).

Answer (score 4):

What you do is perfectly valid, but not very logical. Why not just drop the `setEntireName()` since it just combines two existing fields?

```
public String getEntireName() {
    return firstName + " " + lastname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically it is easier to eliminate the `entireName` property and its setter, and use the getter to perform the concatenation like so:

```
public String getEntireName() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

This is also easier to maintain than updating `entireName` every time `firstName` or `lastName` is changed.